# Are you allowed to save Google static map images?

Tags: google, google-maps

I wanted to know if you are allowed to save a static image of an area of a map so the usage limit does not run out and gets replaced with an quota exceeded image.

If it's allowed, then I can save the image onto my server and link it around my website instead making requests to the Google Static Maps API.

- [Google Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)

I have not seen a policy where you are not allowed, but all I need is confirmation if you are allowed or not so I don't get in any kind of trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [limit](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Limits) is 1000 different images, per person [not site], per day. Are you *really* sure this is even a concern for you?

Anyway, [from the full ToS](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_10_1_3):

> You must not pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: (i) limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily, securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service [...]